# Purpose of "memory path" variable in ATestnetConsumer.sol example

Tags: chainlink

Hello I'm working to create my own custom chainlink job and associated consumer.sol contract. I am using the example "ATestnetConsumer.sol" contract as a guide. (https://github.com/smartcontractkit/documentation/blob/main/_includes/samples/APIRequests/ATestnetConsumer.sol) I am confused regarding the purpose of the req variable and the path string array. What is the purpose of these when the chainlink node executes the job?

```
function requestEthereumLastMarket(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumLastMarket.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    string[] memory path = new string[](4);
    path[0] = "RAW";
    path[1] = "ETH";
    path[2] = "USD";
    path[3] = "LASTMARKET";
    req.addStringArray("path", path);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }
```

Edit: I did figure out what the path variable is for, it controls how you want the jsonparse function to run. For example the path listed above will parse down like this:

```
{"RAW": {"ETH" : {"USD" : { "LASTMARKET" : value
```

Comment: nice, have you seen the tasks docs? https://docs.chain.link/docs/tasks/

Answer (score 0):

The `string[] memory path` is the `path` for the chainlink node to walk to get data from the JSON responose.

For example, if your json looks like this:

```json
{
  cat: {
    tabby: 7,
    cool: 2
  }
}
```

And you wanted the `cool` value of `2`, your `path` would be:

```
string[] memory path = new string[](2);
path[0] = "cat";
path[1] = "cool";
req.addStringArray("path", path);
```